# Git: revert on older commit

Tags: github, commit, head, revert

I did some changes on my git repo and did some commits. Here is what I want to do, say my git history looks as HEAD --> c1 --> c2 --> c3 --> c4. 
Questions
1) Now if I revert c1, does it revert all c2, c3, c4 as well ? My understanding it reverts only c1 and leave c2, c3, c4 as is.
2) Now I want to revert all c1, c2, c3 and c4 and move back to HEAD. What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert will create a commit that will undo the changes of the revision you want to revert.

So if you do:

```
git revert c1
```

You will end with:

> revertC1 -> (previous HEAD) -> c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 ...

And It will only revert that commit changes.

So, for your scenario where you want to remove four commits previos to the HEAD:

> HEAD -> c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4

which is the same as:

> HEAD -> HEAD~1 -> HEAD~2 -> HEAD~3 -> HEAD~4

If you want to remove the four commits before the current one. you can do

```
git revert HEAD~5..HEAD~1
```

You will be prompted to create the commit messages for each revert, and perhaps to solve conflicts.

In case you **HAVE NOT PUSHED** your changes, what I would do to keep the history log clean would be:

Undo the current commit and keep the code changes

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Store the code changes

```
git stash
```

Undo the last four commits and erase code changes

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
```

Make sure I delete any created files and directories

```
git clean -di
```

Re apply the changes from the top commit which is the one I wanted to keep

```
git stash pop
```

*Fix conflicts in case there will be
When there are no conflicts. Commit my changes

```
git commit -am "My new changes"
```

If ready to push, push.

```
git push
```

**This, only if you HAVEN'T PUSHED your changes.**

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this help you solve your issue, please mark it as the accepted answer :D

Answer (score 0):

If you revert c1 it back source to c1 state, but it will create new commit(c5) with all changes from c4 to c1.

```
[HEAD]--> c1 --> c2 --> c3 --> c4 --> c5 (c1 state)
           |__________________________/\
                     revert
```